# Elasticsearch: how to add "nested query" into (nested) filter

Tags: elasticsearch

My structure:

- Person: type object.
- Person.Cars: type nested.
- Person.Cars.Radios: type nested.

I want to write a query that should find all person with:

- Car X
- Car year from 40 to 100
- Radio in the car Y

> ```
>  {
>       "query": {
>         "nested": {
>           "path": "person.cars",
>           "query": {
>             "bool": {
>               "filter": [
>                 {
>                   "match": {
>                     "person.cars.id": {
>                       "query": "X"
>                     }
>                   }
>                 },
>                 {
>                   "range": {
>                     "person.cars.year": {
>                       "from": 40,
>                       "to": 100
>                     }
>                   }
>                 }
>               ]
>             },
>             "nested": {
>               "path": "person.cars.radios",
>               "query": {
>                 "bool": {
>                   "filter": [
>                     {
>                       "match": {
>                         "person.cars.radios.id": {
>                           "query": "Y"
>                         }
>                       }
>                     }
>                   ]
>                 }
>               }
>             }
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     }
> ```

My response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
                "line": 26,
                "col": 5
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 26,
        "col": 5
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

How to write query like this? I know that I have to move my second nested part, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add, your second nested query as a part of your first bool-filter.

```
 {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "person.cars",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "match": {
                "person.cars.id": {
                  "query": "X"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "person.cars.year": {
                  "from": 40,
                  "to": 100
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "person.cars.radios",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "person.cars.radios.id": {
                            "query": "Y"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: {
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "no [query] registered for [query]",
                "line": 24,
                "col": 17
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "no [query] registered for [query]",
        "line": 24,
        "col": 17
    },
    "status": 400
}

Comment: My version: 6.1.1

Comment: For version 6.2.4 the same problem. This is invalid query. :(

Comment: @AdrianKlimczak Had no time until now to fix the query, glad to see that you've found the solution.

Comment: Can you edit your answer? After that I will accept your answer. :)

Comment: @AdrianKlimczak fixed.

Answer (score 0):

@jordivador you were so close.:) Just remove query key after range filter.

Good idea: use Java API - to check how to write a query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "person.cars",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "match": {
                "person.cars.id": {
                  "query": "X"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "person.cars.year": {
                  "from": 40,
                  "to": 100
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "person.cars.radios",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "person.cars.radios.id": {
                            "query": "Y"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```