# Elasticsearch: include_in_parent - any impact for performance? Any reason why default value is false

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, nested

Could anyone tell me, why the default value for "include_in_parent" is false? I found only information that this property had impact for "highlighting". Doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-nested-type.html

But I cannot find any information for performance or potential problems with using this property.

Maybe someone with bigger experience could tell me more about this? For example I had problem like this: [Elasticsearch: how to add "nested query" into (nested) filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50527876/elasticsearch-how-to-add-nested-query-into-nested-filter)

This solution works, but when we will use “include_in_parent” it will be simpler – no sub-query. I can use the same path for cars and radios. Moreover than we add this property this solution (in this link) is still working, so this is another pros.

I know, that this is a little theoretical question, but we will talk about performance and my question based on my case. ;)

Best regards,
Adrian Klimczak